# unexpected token in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/Client/privacy-policy.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/sashan/code/titan/src/Client/privacy-policy.js: Unexpected token (7:17)


   5 | const PrivacyPolicy = createReactClass({
   6 |     render() {
>  7 |         return ( <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: htmlContent} } />);
     |                  ^
   8 |     }
   9 | });
  10 | export default PrivacyPolicy;
```

This is my babel config:

```
babel: {
        presets: [
            ["@babel/preset-env", {
                "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead",
                "modules": false,
                // This adds polyfills when needed. Requires core-js dependency.
                // See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            }]
        ],
    }
```

This is how bable config is used:

```
 {
     test: /\.js$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: CONFIG.babel
      },
 },
```

How can I resolve the compiler error? I just want to load some static html content.

Comment: Well, that's JSX syntax, not JavaScript. You'll need to transpile that as well.

Comment: @Roy Trailing commas are optional but allowed

Comment: You need to use [`preset-react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) for transpiling react jsx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include **[@babel/preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react)** in your babel config for it to compile JSX

Try this

## In your command line

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

## In your babel config

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Div needs a closing tag, it is not an element that can be written `<div\>` rather make sure to write `<div ....></div>`

Comment: Not in JSX. Tags can be _auto-closing_, so `<div />` is also valid